# React Native - Update "affectedRows: 0" and Delete is undefined

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Good day, I'm trying to have a **Update** and **Delete** in my app by id for each item that will be displayed. Unfortunately, my output in my app is nothing and in my console.log for my Update say's "affectedRows:0" and there's no updated data in my database, and in my Delete my console.log say's error or null. I'm not sure what I'am missing out here, please help me.

Here's my code

**My Update code:**

```
submit = () => {
    fetch('http://192.168.254.***:****/SendOrder/update', {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            spcl_req: this.state.SplOrder,
            order_quantity: this.state.count,
            order_type: this.state.DineIn,
            //order_type: this.state.TakeOut
        })
    }).then(res => res.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson))
            console.log(responseJson);
        })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
}
```

**Update_Backend:**

```
router.put('/update', function(req,res){
    db.query('Update orders Set order_quantity=?, order_type=?, spcl_req=? Where order_id=?', [req.body.order_quantity, req.body.order_type, req.body.spcl_req, req.body.order_id], function(error, rows, field) {
        if(error) throw error;
        console.log(rows);
        res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    })
```

**My Delete code:**

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
    this.state = { deleteOrder: null }

delete = () => {
    fetch('http://192.168.254.101:3307/SendOrder/delete_order/' + this.state.deleteOrder, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    }).then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData.rows)
    }).done();
}
```

**Delete_Backend:**

```
router.delete('/delete_order/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    db.query('Delete from orders where order_id=?', req.params.order_id, function(error, rows, field) {
        if(!!error)console.log('error');
        else {
            console.log(rows);
            res.end('success delete');
        }
    })
});
```

ScreenShots:

[image: UI]

[image: Nodemon - console.log]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are sending the wrong params from the frontend and trying to access them. In first request if you see you are not sending the req.body.order_id and in the second delete request backend you are trying to access req.params.order_id which is undefined while your route is /delete_order/:id. So for this you need to use req.params.id.